# SE App reputation widget shows 1138 reputation

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-widgets

Today, I've put in my Android KitKat home screen the SE App widget (reputation panels).

These reputation panels shows **1138** when the OS hasn't loaded yet. Also, the icons aren't shown correctly.

Here's a screenshot.

[image: Bug.]

In the widget of the left, there should be 328 rep. points from *Arqade.SE* and in the widget of the right, there should be 138 rep. points from *Photography.SE*.

- OS: MiUi 7 (Android KitKat)
- SE App: 1.0.83
- Device: Xiaomi Mi3

Comment: I believe they're called ['widgets'](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html) @ShadowWizard cc/@spund3

Comment: Huh, turns out there is even a tag for that. Well. no widget for me so can't see it happening, but this indeed is on topic here. /cc @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ